# _vti_bin/listdata.svc unavailable for subsite

Tags: sub-site, listdata.svc

I am unable to connect to vti_bin/listdata.svc for a specific subsite, although it works for other subsites in the same site collection. I am a site collection administrator and I'm working from a client PC.

On the broken subsite, when trying to connect via a browser I am prompted for my credentials - I've tried many different ones but none work. It is also broken when trying to connect to this service in Excel.

Any idea why it would be broken for just one subsite? I can't see that it would be permissions I have tried to access it as a site collection admin and users with full control over the site.

Comment: have you checked the ULS logs to see if you can get a detailed error message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there was a column in a separate list (but on the same subsite) that was illegally named (a user named a column with just a fullstop). This was causing the `listdata.svc` service to fail.